# Is it possible to Bitlocker encrypt the system disk of another computer?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker

I have been using Bitlocker on my main home PC for many years now and am very happy with it. It requires a password on boot and that's it; otherwise it's invisble.

I have a new laptop which came with Windows 10, but not the professional edition. I tried VeraCrypt to encrypt the whole disk, but on two occassions Windows updates have rendered the system unusable, once while on the road which was quite annoying. It is recoverable but it's extra hassle that seems unecessary.

I don't want to pay $99 to upgrade my laptop to Windows 10 Professional. It seems like too much to pay, especially when in Linux and OS X encryption is included by default for free. I live in a developing country and $99 is not an amount to be sneezed at.

If I manage to get the hard drive out of my new laptop, would it be possible to plug it into my main PC and encrypt it using Bitlocker, and then return the drive to the laptop and continue to boot and run Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a new laptop which came with Windows 10, but not the professional edition. I tried VeraCrypt to encrypt the whole disk, but on two occasions Windows updates have rendered the system unusable, once while on the road which was quite annoying. It is recoverable but it's extra hassle that seems unnecessary.

BitLocker actually has the same problem.  However, BitLocker protection is automatically suspended, when a feature update is installed.  This was actually a recent change to the installation process of feature updates.  **In the past you would have to manually suspend BitLocker protection in order to successfully install a feature update.**

> I don't want to pay $99 to upgrade my laptop to Windows 10 Professional. It seems like too much to pay, especially when in Linux and OS X encryption is included by default for free. I live in a developing country and $99 is not an amount to be sneezed at.

You can either use Veracrypt and temporarily suspend it's protection or upgrade to Windows 10 Professional and that will happen automatically with BitLocker.  I believe with Veracrypt, in order to suspend disk encrypt, it involves decrypting the entire drive.  You can of request a similar feature be added to Veracrypt.  *Unfortunately, there are currently only two full disk encryption suites, that are actually compatible with Windows.*

> If I manage to get the hard drive out of my new laptop, would it be possible to plug it into my main PC and encrypt it using Bitlocker, and then return the drive to the laptop and continue to boot and run Windows?

`Windows 10 Home` does not support system disk encryption.  **If you were to encrypt the system disk of your laptop using your `Windows 10 Professional` installation, Windows 10 Home would be unable to boot.**

Comment: You might want to verify the actual upgrade price from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Professional is actually $99.